# How can I insert a console in to a pyGame Window?

Tags: python, user-interface, console, pygame, frontend

I'm making a text adventure, and I want to have pyGame animations and illustrations and a HUD!

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/585/img20110518075206.jpg/]

How can I insert this console?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I'm pretty sure that's impossible. If you want a console within a Pygame screen then you'll have to write your own, or find one written by someone else (e.g. http://pygame.org/project-pygame-console-287-.html)

Comment: ++. Implementing a basic console is much easier than it sounds

Comment: Would you mind giving me some sample code for implementing a basic console? I'm trying to use the pyGame-console library, but I seem to be having compatibility issues with 3.1

Comment: I've never tried implementing a console in Pygame - I had assumed it would be tricky. But if Eli says it's easier than it sounds I might give it a go later. Sounds like and interesting project.

Answer (score 0):

For your game, you can use [subsurface](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#Surface.subsurface), for the different screen 'sections'.

Using python 3x will have issues with multiple libraries, that are not precompiled for you. **If you can, it will simplify things to Use 2.7** or 2.6. (There is a python2.7 binary, but not on the front page)

A console isn't too hard. You need to break down the components, deciding what you need.
Start with a miniproject, implementing features one at a time.

1. keyboard input, print letters to console
2. render text from a string

   1. blit cached text. **will have demo code later, if you are interested**
3. `dict()` of strings, for commands, with values of function names.
4. draw the last 10 lines of text
5. up = scroll through command history
6. allow command aliases, like "n" and "north" will point to move_north

   1. Implement this using a class: Command() . Which stores a list of all aliases.

commands = { "n" : move_north, "s" : move_south, "fps" : toggle_fps, "help" : print_help }

On enter, call the dict's value, if key exists:

```
if cmd in commands:
    commands[cmd]()
    # same as commands["n"]()
```

You could even have the console's print_help() use the function docstrings.