# How to make a in game command console with pygame

Tags: python, user-interface, pygame

I am making a small 2d overveiw RPG using python and pygame. Right now I'm creating the GUI (text input for talking with NPCs and typing commands).

I want to make it so that I can type in commands while playing the game. I have figured out how to get text input, however how do I parse the input to see if it is a command or something else?

- How do I analyse the input to see if it is a commmand?
- If it is a command, how do I run it?

Example: `\spawn mob 000001` This should spawn a goblin.

**Edit:** [How can I insert a console in to a pyGame Window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6044316/how-can-i-insert-a-console-in-to-a-pygame-window) This looks similar to my problem, but it does not answer my question.

Comment: You will need to parse the input and bind them to function. Try to tokenize the input and match the first argument to a function, and the following argument as parameter for your function.

Comment: Could you do a quick and dirty psudo code example, it would be very helpfull

Comment: This is clearly different from the supposed duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A very simple example of how you could do this:

```
def parse(user_input):
    words = user_input.split()
    command = words[0]        # first word is the command
    parameters = words[1:]    # the rest are parameters for the command
    if command == 'spawn':
        spawn(*parameters)
    elif command == 'foo':
        foo(*parameters)
    # etc.
    else:
        print('Command not recognised')

def spawn(type_, number):
    print('spawning', type_, number)

parse('spawn mob 000001')
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what i need. If i want all the commands to start with / do i just write if command == "/foo"     ?

Comment: yes... I suggest playing with it to understand how it works!

Comment: You're a very wise man ^.^